# Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test in Python (Reporting Siegel's T vs W?)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, paired-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank

While using the Wilcoxon signed rank test in scypy over a subset of populations, I noticed that my test score was reported as zero for an array of differences whose distribution of medians is heavily skewed positive (n=2500, with sign function large and positive).  I then noticed that scypy seems to be reporting Siegel's T for the test statistic, and not W-per their documentation.

I've been trying to find some documentation on how Siegel's T is defined so I can approximate W and determine if my paired medians over each population are significantly different in either direction, but outside of Wikipedia have been unable to find a mention, let alone a derivation.    Could someone help me 'convert' between the two?  Thanks!

Comment: Which definition of W are you using? There are several possibilities.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the reply.  I'm currently using the sum of signed ranks for all matched pairs.

I noticed though that the scypy returned test statistic partitions the set  of paired differences above into two: those pairs with negative signs, and those with positive.  It then returns the smaller of the two.  This seems to be consistant with Siegel's T, and is stated without proof that the two are equal for two sided tests. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test.  I've tried to find the definition of Siegel's T-but have yet to!

Comment: Ran into a character limit- I mean to say the scpy implementation partitions the set of paired differences into those negative and those positive- and computes "W'- the sum of the ranks of the differences above or below zero, whichever is smaller